# Using HOME variable in crontab result in broken jobs

Tags: linux, bash, debian, ubuntu, cron

I have this crontab file with a lot (100+) of jobs that execute some commands in the same directory, suppose `~/Documents/`. Instead of `cd ~/Documents/ && <command>` for every jobs, I can use the cron `HOME` variable to change cron working directory, as explained in [man crontab 5](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) (I've discovered this only recently).

However, if I set this in crontab:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
HOME=/home/user/Documents
```

every jobs that start with `cd ~/Documents/` all of a sudden they don't work anymore. Same if the path is quoted and with/without last backslash.

After a lot of trial-and-error, I can say that is the `~` that doesn't work (it doesn't expand, I guess), because if I type the absolute path to Documents it works great. I've already tried to also add `SHELL=/bin/bash`.

I want to keep backward compatibility to all this kind of jobs so I can edit and test them one-by-one, and don't want to broke other jobs that have ~ in their command. What can I do?

Comment: `HOME=/home/user/Documents` - this doesn't look right. Normally $HOME is `/home/username`.

Comment: `~` means `$HOME`. So when you set `HOME=/home/user/Documents`, `~/Documents` expands to `/home/user/Documents/Documents`. It's not a problem of it _not expanding_; it's just expanding to a different value than you want. This is part of why POSIX [recommends you use lower-case names for your own variables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) (search for "reserved for applications"), so you don't unintentionally override ones like `HOME` or `PATH` that reflect or modify how OS-provided tools work.

Answer (score 6):

If you set `HOME=/home/user/Documents` then `cd ~/Documents` is equivalent to `cd /home/user/Documents/Documents`, which presumably fails.

I should point out that nowhere in the referenced documentation ([`man 5 crontab`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)) does it say that you "*can use the `cron` `HOME` variable to change cron working directory*".

Conclusion? Don't change `$HOME`